# Cucumber/Capybara Selecting Button from Specific Class?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

So i've ran into an issue, im trying to click a button...which unfortunately has the same text (IE there are 2 buttons on the page which the same text, basically a save button)

Lets pretend the button text is just "Save".

I did notice that they had different classes.

```
<button data-action="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Save</button>
```

whereas the other button is:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary set-right">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save
</button>
```

I know glypicon is just an icon set....but they both seem to belong to the same class? but have different class names? (Sorry im not familiar with Rails)

It doesn't honestly matter which one I select as they both have the same function. I've seen where you can use xpath? but aren't we supposed to use css selectors or something now? (As in thats the newest way?) I may be wrong....

Could I use something like:

```
find(:xpath, '//button[@class="btn-save"]').click
```

Im trying to avoid "rails" only solutions, as not all the websites I test on are rails based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have various possibilities:

1) Find the button by its **class**

```
find(button.btn.btn-primary.btn-save).click
```

2) Find the button by its **css selector** or **xpath** (you can copy them using Google Chrome: right click -> Inspect -> right click on your element -> copy css or xpath)

```
find(:css, "your button css selector").click

find(:xpath, "your button xpath").click
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a specific one? isn't the css selector the newer/preferred method? or am I making that up?

Comment: the class could give you some problems if you have more than an element in the page with the same class. but anyway you could avoid it with the `within` method, that allows you to look for an element in a specific area of the page. `css selector` and `xpath` are more flexible but they lose something in terms of readability, even if you can avoid long `css selector/xpath` creating custom selectors https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#xpath-css-and-selectors

Comment: I used the Xpath selector as right clicking gave me no copy css. But it did end up working! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If both buttons really do the same thing then you could always just do

```
first(:button, 'Save', minimum: 1).click
```

which will be less prone to breakage as your page structure changes than using an xpath selector.  The minimum:1 option will just make #first wait a bit until at least one button is on the page (like find would) - it may not be necessary depending on your test structure