# "a is null" error while clicking on element containing javascript in Capybara (Selenium)

Tags: ruby, selenium, click, capybara, headless

Unable to click on this element in Capybara:

```
<a href="javascript:selectItemClientUpd('12345678', 'some_text')">content</a>
```

Command:

**find("a").click**

Error message:

**a is null (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)**

There are no other links in the page. The correct link is found (checked), but its not possible to click it. click_link, click_button dont work.

Comment: why don't you find it by its css selector or xpath? try it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34318639/1033737

Comment: Theres was no problem finding it, but clicking. However I got past the problem and will add an answer.

Comment: Please post the stack trace - you shouldn't be rescuing errors in your tests it'll hide all sorts of problems

Comment: @TomWalpole the answer is now edited, do you know alternate ways to avoid the problem? Your Capybara-Fu is much appreciated.

Comment: @MiikaPalokangas  Ok - so the fact that clicking that button is closing (removing I'm assuming) the iframe is a big clue there.  It appears there may be a bug in selenium with returning to the parent frame when the current frame is removed.  Not sure if there's anything Capybara can do about it - I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: @MiikaPalokangas  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1691  The fix will be released in Capybara 2.7.1 in the next couple of days - until then you can use the 2.7_stable branch of Capybara if desired.