# How to click on a button that can only be identified by a custom attribute?

Tags: ruby, css-selectors

I'm just getting into automated testing and I've been writing some code for a fake site that a friend set up for me for testing. The test I'm writing is meant to click on an "Add to Cart" button, however each of the button have the same exact class and the only way to really identify them is through the custom attributes.

This is the code for the button i'm trying to click

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-block addItem" data-id="1" data-name="Chocolate Cups" data-price="1.00">Add to Cart</a>
```

(I'm trying to click on the button by using the data-id attribute)

Each of the buttons have the same class so they can't be identified that way otherwise an error pops up saying that the result is "Ambiguous" and thus can't do it.

I used the code below and managed to identify a specific button however I'm not sure how I would now click the button.

```
Given("I'm on the sweets list page") do
  visit("https://sweetshop.netlify.com/sweets.html")
end

When("I click {string} button") do |string|
  page.should have_css("*[data-id='1']")
end

Then("add the item to cart") do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```rb
Then("add the item to cart") do
  find(:css, "*[data-id='1']").click
end
```

or

```rb
Then("add the item to cart") do
  find(:xpath, "//*[@data-id='1']").click
end
```

Similar post: [Cucumber/Capybara Selecting Button from Specific Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318242/cucumber-capybara-selecting-button-from-specific-class)